# disk plug cache after first time

Tags: python, linux, driver, device, ceph

I need to develop one feature that likes disk hotplug. I write some `udev` rules to monitor disk to execute one `python` script when udev triggered.

Question:

when I pull the disk first time, `lsblk, lsscsi, udev, megacli` all can monitor, `/dev/sda` change to be `/dev/sdg`, `udev` also can be triggered and py script be executed successfully, first time disk plug is also normal.

But the second time or more, I pull the previous `/dev/sdg`, `lsblk, lsscsi, udev` all can not sense, the std output list also contain `dev/sdg`, and `udev` doesn't find `remove event`, the script is also not executed, `megacli` can find the lack of disk

Now I need `udev` monitor disk plug real time to execute script, is someone has experience in this question ?

**my `udev` rules:**

```
KERNEL=="sd[a-z]", ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", RUN+="/usr/bin/python /root/disk_plug.py %k add"
KERNEL=="sd[a-z]", ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="block", RUN+="/usr/bin/python /root/disk_plug.py %k remove"
```

This is my test script: **`/root/disk_plug.py`**

```
import sys
import time
disk = sys.argv[1]
event = sys.argv[2]
with open('/root/disk.txt', 'a') as f:
    msg = event + '-' + disk + '-' + str(time.time())
    f.write(msg + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to umount before pulling out